# Add and remove arbitrary input fields from Swagger UI in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a Spring Boot application with `springfox-swagger-ui`. I need to:

- Make Swagger UI display input field for a parameter that does not appear among the request handler params in my controller. For example, the request contains a `hashCode` parameter, which I verify with a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and then I don't need anymore, thus I don't list it among the request handler params. But I want to have it in Swagger UI.
- Remove an input field from Swagger UI that corresponds to a parameter that I have in my request handler in my controller. For example, the request contains a `userId`, which I use to construct an `User` object with a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and then inject it into the request handler by adding a parameter of type `User`. Thus I don't want Swagger UI to create `User` input field, but instead a `userId` input field.

To summarize, I need to show an input field in Swagger UI that does not correspond to any request handler parameter, and I need to hide an input field in Swagger UI that corresponds to a request handler parameter. How to do this?